# How to use events on an Embedded Firebird database connection?

Tags: c#, events, firebird, firebird-embedded, firebird-.net-provider

If I connect to an embedded Firebird database, and create a remote event, I get  System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.. on the constructor.

```
_fbRemoteEvent = new FbRemoteEvent(_fbConnection);  //_fbConnection is valid and Opened
```

Looking at source code from call stack, it leads to FesDatabase.cs with

```
RemoteEvent IDatabase.CreateEvent()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

I use the embedded version for automated tests purpose ... Is there something I can do to get event from the embedded database in a test context?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Events are unfortunately not supported in embedded mode in Firebird -- they can only be run over the network. This is due to the fact that the whole protocol of setting up an event handler involves setting up a second network connection to the FB server -- as you're not using a network connection at all in embedded mode, this won't work.

Comment: Thank you Gab. it's good to know the reason of this limitation. I will use a normal server for my automated tests with a little more intrusive setup.

Comment: Events do work on Firebird Embedded, however it is possible that this is not implemented in the Firebird .NET provider (or was not implemented at the time of this post).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Is there a working implementation of event usage on Firebird Embedded? As I recall, the event handling handshake required a network connection, which (I thought) is by definition not available in embedded mode.

Comment: @gab I just fixed a bug in Jaybird (JDBC driver) that prevented it from working; now there is no problem. See also http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4F82CF73.5070803%40lawinegevaar.nl&forum_name=firebird-devel

Answer (score 1):

Events are supported in Firebird Embedded, but the Firebird ado.net provider (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient) does not implement support for events when using Firebird Embedded.